# Tradução oficial do bbPress para o idioma Português

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Não encontrei nenhum download oficial do bbPress para o idioma Português. Encontrei no Google todo tipo de sugestão mas creio que é para versões antigas do plugin bbPress.

Já instalei e está totalmente funcional, mas falta os arquivos .po / .mo. Se não, como faço para traduzir o plugin?

Comment: Eu não conhecia muito bem o processo de tradução dos plugins do Wordpress e achava que pudesse existir um repositório de traduções. O @joão-paraná esclareceu como fazer a tradução e o `brasofilo` sugeriu fazer no Site. Foram duas boas propostas e é uma pena que menos de 1% esteja traduzido para Português.

Comment: Não entendi bem o motivo de fechamento aqui. Os que votaram para fechar, foi por ser um pedido de recomendação (existe/onde está a tradução) ou porque não é claro mesmo? @brasofilo Marco você aqui pois você que é o perito em wordpress.

Comment: @bfavaretto, meu motivo foi "não relacionado com programação".

Comment: Não é programação mas está relacionado a configuração de ambiente (no caso Wordpress) e além disso internacionalização de software é assunto de muito interesse para os Brasileiros.

Comment: Na verdade, o ponto levantado pela admin-absoluta é bem válido; os programas envolvidos são populares; a resposta do João Paraná é muito boa;  eu mesmo posso contribuir com algo útil... enfim, [acabo de propor *internacionalização de software* como on-topic lá no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1544/201). E como acho que me equivoquei, vou reverter meu voto de fechamento por um de reabertura.

Comment: Legal @brasofilo, por ora minha missão aqui está cumprida. Vou ficar de olho na pergunta, se ela acabar esquecida fechada, depois de um tempo eu posso reabrir.

Comment: @admin-absoluta, não entendo, a tradução para o PT está em 100% : http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/bbpress/dev/pt-br/default

Answer (score 4):

Se já tiver uma conta em http://translate.wordpress.org use-a do contrario crie uma e se log.

Depois faça download dos arquivos `.po` e `.mo`, versão 2.4 ou mais recente em  http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/bbpress/2.4.x/pt-br/default/export-translations .

**CORREÇÃO:** O link correto é http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/bbpress/dev/pt-br/default como comentatado pelo @brasofilo. O link pra versão 2.4 que aparece no site do bbPress está desatualizado e não deve ser utilizado !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Supondo que os arquivos foram baixados para ~/Downloads e que seu site está em ~/www faça:

```
cd ~/www
cp ~/Downloads/bbpress-dev-pt-br.po  wp-content/languages/bbpress/bbpress-pt_BR.po
cp ~/Downloads/bbpress-dev-pt-br.mo  wp-content/languages/bbpress/bbpress-pt_BR.mo
# conferindo ...
ls -lA wp-content/languages
```

Comment: Link para download do Poedit - [http://poedit.net/download](http://poedit.net/download)

Comment: Vale a pena observar que seria **muito bom** traduzir *lá no site* antes de fazer download. Desse jeito a tradução vai ser incorporada no projeto e vai ficar disponível para toda comunidade.

Comment: Valeu @brasofilo ! Esqueci de mencionar isso.